# How to call Notification Builder.build() on device with API 15?

Tags: android

My device is a galaxy s2 with API 15 on it.
My program has min sdk api 11 and target sdk api 19.
It uses Notification builder and runs fine in the emulator.
Trying to run on device,

```
03-04 09:51:47.503: E/AndroidRuntime(16416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 09:51:47.503: E/AndroidRuntime(16416): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.build
03-04 09:51:47.503: E/AndroidRuntime(16416):    at com.myprogram.NotifyActivity.onReceive(NotifyActivity.java:60)
03-04 09:51:47.503: E/AndroidRuntime(16416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2130)
03-04 09:51:47.503: E/AndroidRuntime(16416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-04 09:51:47.503: E/AndroidRuntime(16416):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
03-04 09:51:47.503: E/AndroidRuntime(16416):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

if I understood correctly, the android docs ask to target highest possible version and to use a support library for devices with lower apis. I installed the support library per instructions at http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: You have to target the support libraries yourself in your source; just adding it to the project isn't enough. The system doesn't just use it

Comment: Ok, I changed my code to use NotificationCompat.Builder instead, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Builder.build() is available since API level 16.

Use the approach below to create a notification.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Notification build(final Builder builder) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        return builder.build();
    } else {
        return builder.getNotification();
    }
}
```

Or you can use

[NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)

Comment: Trying to test your solution, I get a compile error at `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` `Description Resource Path Location Type
The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type`

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` indicates that the `android.app.Notification$Builder.build` method exists in your classpath during compilation, but not during running of your application on device. Have your run you app in other devices? Maybe Samsung changed implementation of this class.

Comment: please see my comment on what I did to fix it.